# How can I obtain a list of our applications' SQL statements that do not make use of indexes?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-server-2017, query-performance

We have a system that processes thousands of statements a second, all running quickly. With so many statements we are looking to fine tune with small improvements to have a knock on large improvement when they are run thousands of times.
In some cases, we found statements doing table scans where they should have done index seeks if the datatype parameter had been correct.
We take a profile of some millions of rows over 10 minutes and save as a table for easier analysis.
Is there a way to search for statements that aren't using indexes. Is searching the showplan XML the best method? If so, what should we search for?

Comment: Have a look at [First responder kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/) of [Brent Ozar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/426/brent-ozar)

Comment: There is a good answer. Did you happen to come across  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/find-queries-performing-full-scans